# C# Library to Make a Media Center Type Application?

Tags: c#, user-interface

I want to make an application with a GUI similar to Windows Media Center or Boxee but I don't know where to start.

Some 2D GUI libraries or links to tutorials on how to make such an application would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest .NET's two built-in GUI libraries: [Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd30h2yb.aspx) or the newer, prettier [Windows Presentation Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx)?  If you're looking for something that can play video files, [VLC's plugin](http://wiki.videolan.org/.Net_Interface_to_VLC) is nice.  Or you can use the [Windows Media Player](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101752) control.

```
<Window x:Class="FullscreenWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        WindowStyle="None"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        Topmost="True"
        Cursor="None">
    <Grid>
        <Label>Hello?</Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Ahh.. I'm not looking to make an app with a "form", I want to make an application with it's own UI such as XBMC or Boxee (Screenshot: http://www.gadgetreview.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/boxee-screenshot.jpg)

Comment: You don't think you can make a GUI that goes full screen in WPF?  I'm revising my answer...